# flask "hello world" can not run in debug model

Tags: python, flask, inotify, pyinotify

I followed official document, installed virtualenv and flask, and then `python hello.py`
But there is something wrong：

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader: inotify events
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 9, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/home/aa/prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 553, in run
    return run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/aa/prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.7-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 609, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval)
  File "/home/aa/prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.7-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 528, in run_with_reloader
    reloader_loop(extra_files, interval)
  File "/home/aa/prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.7-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 436, in reloader_loop
    reloader(fnames, interval=interval)
  File "/home/aa/prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.7-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 464, in _reloader_inotify
    mask = reduce(lambda m, a: m | getattr(EventsCodes, a), mask, 0)
  File "/home/aa/prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.7-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 464, in <lambda>
    mask = reduce(lambda m, a: m | getattr(EventsCodes, a), mask, 0)
AttributeError: type object 'EventsCodes' has no attribute 'IN_DELETE_SELF'
```

my hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

but if without debug that's ok? why?
my /env/lib/python2.7/site-packages:

```
distribute-0.6.10-py2.7.egg
Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg
Werkzeug-0.7-py2.7.egg
easy-install.pth
pip-0.7.2-py2.7.egg
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug triggered by a change in pyinotify's API, which you must also have installed. You could remove pyinotify or use a dirty hack to force it to use stat() instead of pyinotify. To line 496 of `werkzeug/serving.py` try adding (below the part where it attempts to import pyinotify):

```
# dirty hack
reloader = _reloader_stat_loop
reloader_name = "stat() polling"
```

Make sure to also report the bug to the [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) developers.

Comment: Yup, it will be fixed in werkzeug 0.7.1. And there was another similar issue with IPython.